# Print "abracadabra" with 7 different alterations

Tags: code-golf

[*Abracadabra* is a magic word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abracadabra). To make it even more magical, let's make several *alterations* to how it may be written:

1. Change the casing for any subset of characters; for example: `aBrAcAdAbRa`
2. Append an exclamation mark to it: `abracadabra!`
3. Change each occurrence of `a` into a different vowel: `ybrycydybry`
4. Change any single consonant letter into a different consonant which doesn't appear in the original word: `abracadakra` (don't change all occurrences of `b` into `k`, only one!)
5. Change the foreground colour, but not background colour
6. Change the background colour, but not foreground colour
7. Use [fullwidth characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_Fullwidth_Forms_(Unicode_block)): `ａｂｒａｃａｄａｂｒａ` (don't cheat by inserting spaces!)

Output the variants to the screen (or printer) in 8 different lines of text. One variant (not necessarily the first one) should be "base", while all others should differ from it in a single aspect, as described above.

The output may be the same each time your code is run; alternatively, it may be different each time (depending on random numbers or unpredictable values in memory).

If your system can't support some of these alterations (for example, no support for colours on a black-and-white screen; no full-width characters on ASCII-only terminals), use the following replacement alterations:

- Text in inverted colours
- Blinking text
- Different font
- Different font size

But please use these only if your system really doesn't support the original alterations!

Comment: Should this be tagged as [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)?

Comment: At least on some terminals, you can implement the colours using ANSI escape-codes; not sure about the fullwidth part.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 7 different lines of text, since one variant should be "base"? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Each of the 7 spelling aspects has two possible values: "0" and "1". Base line is represented by "0,0,0,0,0,0,0"; 7 additional lines are represented by something like "0,0,1,0,0,0,0".

Comment: For options 1 and 4, as well as the colors of 5 and 6: can we choose/hard-code the alterations, or are they random per run?

Comment: Choose any alteration that is valid. May be random, but I think a constant one is easier to implement.

Comment: Based on the existing answers, I assume I already know the answer: but are the alterations separated or cumulative? E.g. `abracadabra abracadabra! Abracadabra obrocodobro ...` vs `abracadabra abracadabra! Abracadabra! Obrocodobro! ...`. And I assume we can use any order?

Comment: Does "change the casing" means "for every other letter, change its case" or "for any chosen letter, change its case"? I assumed the former in my answer.

Comment: Any non-empty subset of characters. I have updated the post.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes and yes. This was actually already specified.

Comment: I just noticed brainfuck is eliminated because there are not enough replacements for it

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 98 bytes

```
M¶M¶M!¶M¶M¶␛[5mM␛[25m¶␛[7mM␛[27m¶M
M
abracadabra
2=`c
C
T`a`y`!¶.+
4=`c
k
T`l`ａ-ｒ`.+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy/fQNhBShFCHtklHm@b6SkcbmeaC2OZgtjmQ7cvly5WYVJSYnJgCoriMbBOSuZy5QhISEyoTgLr1tLlMQELZQKGchPd7G3Xf752UoKet8v8/AA) `␛` characters above are actual ESC characters in the link, but they don't work in a post. Byte count shows as 86 bytes because link assumes SBCS but this is actually UTF-8. Fifth and sixth lines of output are blinking and inverse video. Explanation:

```
M¶M¶M!¶M¶M¶␛[5mM␛[25m¶␛[7mM␛[27m¶M
M
abracadabra
```

Insert the basic text, but with lines 3, 6 and 7 already altered.

```
2=`c
C
```

Uppercase a letter in line 2.

```
T`a`y`!¶.+
```

Change the vowels in line 4.

```
3=`c
k
```

Change a consonant in line 5.

```
T`l`ａ-ｒ`.+$
```

Use full width characters in line 8.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>263</s> <s>247</s> <s>205</s> <s>202</s> <s>186</s> 165 bytes

```python
p=print;p(s:='abracadabra');p(s+'!')
for j in 0,1,2,3:p(''.join((chr(ord(c)+(j>2)*65248),'Dyk '[j])[c=='dac '[j]]for c in s))
for j in 3,4:p(f'\033[{j}4m{s}\033[0m')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDLbsIwELz7F7gYLmuXKKIkrRCVe@LSUw89phwSJ4GEJrZsUylCHPr4gv4P38QngOOAmqoX787MerSzsjFrUQczqU5FJYUyWDcaaZOKrcGsBX4HELrohUDJNs8zZeVC@C9GFfXq6ZlQ9DtspW7mJJm0unmQRM8ZxImKeZy2BWjLjWEIFOVC4RIXNZ54t97UC@aSAPilKGpC@FoRoVLC6ZiUj1N6c383DWfUg0WzwRCVSxpxxiCNuUPL1ou3Xpr2jAMvtKY5vE6CINqV@7Da6b0Dkwro6c/m17z2kb0o/ioz7/HbNrNJUax1Zm9xHWF4NBr1wqFeP7yAhROaRDW8Sdvi@M3lw/HwcTx8Hg8/rvly73efRIMoCKue78CubsnwP2l3QcidnYDY2Pt2/bV2S3tZnTKw2c8)

Not a very good Python solution, but worth the try. Outputs

1. base case: `abracadabra`
2. exclamation mark appended: `abracadabra!`
3. case swapped: `abracaDabra` (`d` replaced with `D`)
4. vowels replaced: `ybrycydybry` (`a` replaced with `y`)
5. single consonant replaced: `abrakadabra` (`c` replaced with `k`)
6. width filled: `ａｂｒａｃａｄａｂｒａ`
7. with blue foreground: `abracadabra`
8. with blue blackground: `abracadabra`

**How it works?**

The first line sets an alias for `print` and executes steps 1 and 2.

The second line groups \$4\$ steps: 3, 4, 5 and 6.

Therefore, \$0 \leq j \lt 4\$: for step 3, \$j=0\$; for step 4, \$j=1\$; and so on.

Note that for steps 3, 4 and 5, a single letter is replaced by another single letter. This allows us to do

```python
[c,'Dyk '[j]][c=='dac '[j]]
```

Also note that for step 6, ASCII character `a` is 65248 characters apart from `ａ`:

```python
chr(ord(c)+65248)
```

Since they're different types of replacement, we can filter it using

```python
(j>2)*65248
```

where it'll be evaluated to 65248 only for \$j=3\$ (step 6).

Since this conditional is not lazy-evaluated, we must add a space after `Dyk` and `dac` for considering the case where \$j=3\$.

The third line handles the colors.

**Changes**

*-16 bytes* by reducing the lambdas to a curry.

*-42 bytes* by assuming that "change the casing" means "change the case of any letter" as other answers did.

*-3 bytes* by inlining the `j > 2` condition

*-16 bytes* by using f-strings instead of `print(..., sep='')`

*-21 bytes* by inlining the lambdas and using a generator comprehension

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 114 bytes

*-2 thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) (and another -4 from there)*

Includes the unprintable character `\x1b`.

```javascript
_=>`ab*
Ab*
ab*!
obrocodobro
ak*
[36mab*
[46mab*
ａｂｒａｃａｄａｂｒａ`.split`*`.join`racadabra[0m`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i4hMUmLyxGIgbQiV35SUX5yfgqI4krM1uKSjjY2ywWpkI42gTDe7218v7fp/d5JYEYzmGxBFkzQKy7IySxJ0ErQy8rPzEsoSkxOTElMKkqUjjbITfifnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66RpqGp@R8A)

#### Output

[image: output]

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ANSI-color codes, but can't the `37` and `40` in your program be `0` to reset them to their defaults?

Comment: [111](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i4hUYvLUYsrUUuRKz@pKD85PwVEcSVmS2txSUcbm@UmgmgTMP1@b@P7vU3v904CM5rBZAuyYIJecUFOZkmCVoJeVn5mXkJSUWJyYkoikJKONshN@J@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGmoan5HwA) [works fine on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA2Ft.png)

Comment: @l4m2 Interesting hack ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 61 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.•ÒÔt_º°•D©™®'!«®žOÂ‡®'f1ǝ₆41‚ε®27çDr"[ÿmÿÿ[0m"«}`®Ç65248+çJ»
```

Alteration options in the same order as the challenge description.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AWoAlf9vc2FiaWX//y7igKLDksOUdF/CusKw4oCiRMKp4oSiwq4nIcKrwq7Fvk/DguKAocKuJ2Yxx53igoY0MeKAms61wq4yN8OnRHIiW8O/bcO/w79bMG0iwqt9YMKuw4c2NTI0OCvDp0rCu///)

I misunderstood the challenge at first and thought the alternations were cumulative, which is actually shorter in 05AB1E (**52 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) - non-competing**):

```
.•ÒÔt_º°•='!«=žOÂ‡=™='f1ǝ=Ç65248+çJ=₆41‚vy…[ÿm27çìì=
```

(Cumulative) alteration options in the order 2,3,1,4,7,5,6.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AVoApf9vc2FiaWX//y7igKLDksOUdF/CusKw4oCiPSchwqs9xb5Pw4LigKE94oSiPSdmMcedPcOHNjUyNDgrw6dKPeKChjQx4oCadnnigKZbw79tMjfDp8Osw6w9//8)

**Explanation:**

```python
.•ÒÔt_º°•       # Push compressed string "abracadabra"
         ©      # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
D               # Duplicate it
 ™              # Titlecase the copy
®               # Push base-string `®` again
 '!«           '# Append "!"
®               # Push base-string `®` again
 žO             # Push vowels builtin "aeiouy"
   Â            # Bifurcate it (short for Duplicate & Reverse copy): "yuoiea"
    ‡           # Transliterate all characters (so "a"s become "y"s)
®               # Push base-string `®` again
    ǝ           # Insert
 'f            '# an "f"
   1            # at 0-based index 1
®               # Push base-string `®` again
 Ç              # Convert it to a list of codepoint integers
  65248+        # Add 65248 to each
        ç       # Convert each integer back to a character
         J      # Join it back together to a string
₆41‚            # Push pair [36,41]
    ε           # Map over them:
                #  (implicitly push the current integer)
     ®          #  Push base-string `®` again
      27ç       #  Push 27, and convert it to a character with this codepoint (␛)
         Dr     #  Duplicate, then reverse the four items on the stack
     "[ÿmÿÿ[0m" #  Push this string, replacing the `ÿ` one by one with the values
     «          #  Append it to the remaining ␛
    }`          # After the map: pop and push both strings to the stack
      »         # Join all strings on the stack by newlines
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

The cumulative program is pretty similar, except uses `=` (print with trailing newline without popping the string). And the `␛[0m` to reset the colors aren't necessary.

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•ÒÔt_º°•` is `"abracadabra"`.